# Restarting nodejs server on crashing in an electronjs app

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am building an electron app and using nodejs as the backend server within the app.

How can I auto-restart the nodejs server if it encounters a crash?

I am currently using pm2 and using the following code in electron's main.js file

```
 var pm2 = require("pm2");

 pm2.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(2);
  }

  pm2.start(
    {
      name: "mydesktopapp",
      script: "./server/server.js", // nodejs Script to be run
      exec_mode: "cluster",
      instances: 1,
      max_memory_restart: "5000M", // Optional: Restarts your app if it reaches 5GB
      noDaemonMode: true,
      watch: true
    },
    function(err, apps) {
      pm2.disconnect(); // Disconnects from PM2
      console.error(`Unable to start PM2: ${err}`);
      if (err) throw err;
    }
  );
});
```

But this does not seem to work, as its throwing the following error:

```
Unable to start PM2: null
```

How do you guys handle this?

Thanks

Comment: It might be because you are running your app in non daemon mode.

Comment: Does it really matter if i run the app in non deamon mode?